# Eclipse plugin: create a treeview that displays all the deprecated methods

Tags: java, eclipse, treeview

I'm new to Eclipse plugin development and I'm trying to implement a treeview that displays all the deprecated methods used in the current/selected project.

It should look like this:

```
-jdom
--- method1
-------file1 that uses this method
-------file2 that uses this method
--- method2
-------file1 that uses this method
--- method3
-------file1 that uses this method
-log4j
----method1
-------file1 that uses this method
--- method2
--- method3
```

Eclipse has this very good feature that tells you the API that you are using has been deprecated by striking through the <strike>method</strike>.

Is there a way I can get a full list of all the deprecated methods? I'm sure this can be one given what Eclipse can do.

Any explanation on how Eclipse does the strikethrough with reference to the code is also appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse is using the JDT [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using that and it's going well so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out in this way:

```
       for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> entry : treeMap
                .entrySet()) {
            if (!entry.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                LibraryModel libraryModel = new LibraryModel(entry.getKey());
                root.addLibrary(libraryModel);
                for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> methodToFileEntry : entry
                        .getValue().entrySet()) {
                    MethodModel methodModel = new MethodModel(
                            methodToFileEntry.getKey());
                    libraryModel.addMethod(methodModel);
                    for (String fileName : methodToFileEntry.getValue()) {
                        FileModel fileModel = new FileModel(fileName, fileName);
                        methodModel.addFile(fileModel);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The HashMap stores the information I get from visiting AST

```
          for (MethodInvocation method : visitor.getMethods()) {
                if (method.resolveMethodBinding().isDeprecated()) {
                    for (IAnnotationBinding iab: method.resolveMethodBinding()
                            .getAnnotations()) {
                        for (IMemberValuePairBinding ivab: iab.getAllMemberValuePairs()) {
                            System.out.println(ivab.getKey());
                            System.out.println(ivab.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                    String deprecatedMethod = method.getName().toString();
                    String fileName = parse.getJavaElement().getResource()
                            .getName();
                    String packageName = method.resolveMethodBinding()
                            .getDeclaringClass().getQualifiedName();
                    String library = findLibrary(packageName);
                    if (treeMap.get(library).isEmpty()
                            || treeMap.get(library).get(deprecatedMethod)
                                    .isEmpty()) {
                        Map<String, Set<String>> innerMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
                        Set<String> fileNames = new HashSet<String>();
                        fileNames.add(fileName);
                        innerMap.put(deprecatedMethod, fileNames);
                        treeMap.put(library, innerMap);
                    } else {
                        Map<String, Set<String>> innerMap = treeMap
                                .get(library);
                        innerMap.get(deprecatedMethod).add(fileName);
                    }

                }
            }
```

This successfully gave me the tree I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

To get all deprecated method : here I'm using java.util.Date class

```
Method[] methods = java.util.Date.class.getMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
        java.lang.annotation.Annotation annotations[] = methods[i]
                .getAnnotations();

        for (int j = 0; j < annotations.length; j++) {
            if (annotations[j] instanceof Deprecated) {
                System.out.println("Deprecated method Name : "
                        + methods[i].getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I worked it out in another way but was too busy to post my solution.